# Click anywhere using video tag html5

Tags: html, html5-video

Is there a configuration for having the video start/pause when clicked anywhere on the object?

Here's my code:

```
<video id="video_player" controls="controls" poster=""> 
    <source  id="video_mp4" src="video.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' />
</video>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<video onclick="playPause()" id="video_player" controls="controls" poster=""> 
    <source  id="video_mp4" src="video.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' />
</video>    

<script>
var myVideo = document.getElementById("video_player");    
function playPause() { 
    if (myVideo.paused) 
        myVideo.play(); 
    else 
        myVideo.pause(); 
}
</script>
```

try something like this

Comment: Not sure what is wrong, but it only stops for a second then goes on right away. I'm using touch on a tablet.